# backBarButtonItem can not hide

Tags: ios, swift

This problem is on ios 9 and ios 10.
When I present a navigationviewController，the backBarButtonItem can not hide,but in super class I set this

```
override func pushViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        super.pushViewController(viewController, animated: animated)
        viewController.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
        let backItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "navigationItem_back_img"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(backItemOnClick(_:)))
        backItem.title = ""
        viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backItem
    }
```

[image]

When I push this navigationViewController,i cann't got this problem

Answer (score 3):

Add this line `self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)` in viewDidLoad() on the view controller where you want to hide the backbar button item.

Comment: No, I think my problem is not in this code because I have used this code. In the following versions of ios10 (included), when I use the `navigationController.push` method, it's fine, but when I use the `present` popup view, the return button's `_UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView` is not hidden, which may be causing the `leftbarbuttonItem` The reason for moving down, I want to know how to hide this view.

Answer (score 1):

Add below line in `viewDidLoad()` or `viewWillAppear()`:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```

or

```
self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest to use any other technique to show the viewController instead of pushing it into the navigation controller. It will hide the back button and also can be dismissed easily after serving your purpose from your main ViewController. Use present modally or present as popover and then dismiss that after your work accordingly. 
If you are not willing to do so then I think above answers will serve your purpose. But my suggestion for your problem will be presenting the view controller differently, it will also help in keeping the code clean and more understandable. 
Do leave a message if you want to discuss it or know more about my approach.